# If Namespaces can only have a Global Scope how can there be Nested Namespaces?

Tags: c++, nested, namespaces

I read these 2 pieces of codes and their descriptions and thought that they were clashing with each other.

> 1. Namespace definition can appear only in a global scope.

```
void f()
{
    namespace space1{

    }
}
// So this is not allowed as space1 is local to f()
```

> 2. Namespaces can be nested

```
namespace namespace1{
    int i;
    namespace namespace2{
       int j;
    }
}
```

In this case won't namespace2 be local to namespace1 thus resulting in an error?

Comment: Please mention where you're quoting from.

Comment: It is not true that namespaces can only be at global scope.

Comment: The "global scope" is really the global *namespace* scope. Namespaces can be defined in any namespace scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your quote is wrong. A more correct description would be:

> Namespace definitions are only allowed at namespace scope, including
> the global scope.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace